# ansible "sed: can't read file: No such file or directory"

Tags: ansible, file-permissions

I have an Ansible playbook that should execute a script. This Script should add lines of code to a file. Note that the playbook is bigger then this one role though all other steps of the ansible-playbook work. The script also works when executed directly on the puppet server. I suspect that it is a permissions issue, though i am not sure how to solve the problem.

Note: The ansible playbook is getting executed as ansible user. The script and the file with the added lines are owned by usr ansible and grp ansible. Rights are: 0755.
The file to be changed is also at the same location as the script.

script name:

```
createlines.sh
```

file with the added lines:

```
testfile.py
```

hosts:

```
puppet
```

ansible command:

```
ansible-playbook deployment-test.yml --ask-become-pass
```

playbook:

```
---
- name: add lines in file
  hosts: Puppet
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  vars_files:
    - vars/gpv-test.yml
  roles:
    - run-script
```

roles/run-script:

```
---
- name: Execute the createlines script
  command: sh /var/opt/alu/deploy/hieradata/createlines.sh
```

Error message(is extremly big and constantly repeats itself):

Start of error message:

```
     fatal: [puppet]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sh", "/var/opt/alu/deploy/hieradata/createlines.sh"], "delta": "0:00:00.467213", "end": "2018-12-10 15:33:25.429726", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2018-12-10 15:33:24.962513", "stderr": "sed: can't read testfile.py: No such file or directory\nsed: can't read testfile.py: No such file or directory\nsed: can't read testfile.py: No such file or directory\nsed: can't read testfile.py........
.....can't read gen_prod_trm_test_yaml.py: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["sed: can't read testfile.py: No such file or directory", "sed: can't read testfile.py: No such file or directory", "sed: can't read testfile.py: No such file or directory", "sed: can't read testfile.py: No such file or directory",........
```

End of error message:

```
........"sed: can't read testfile.py: No such file or directory", "sed: can't read testfile.py: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Does someone see what could be wrong?

---

Edit:
createlines.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
group_2=(/tmp/${today}/group-2/*)
group_3=(/tmp/${today}/group-3/*)
group_4=(/tmp/${today}/group-4/*)
group_5=(/tmp/${today}/group-5/*)
file="testfile.py"
#filessha1="../../../testfolder/testfolder/group-2/"
#sha1keyy=`sha1sum "${filesha1}"`
#echo "${sha1key}"
#echo "$today"
######GROUP-2
for i in ${group_2[@]}; do
   #echo $i
   #echo ${i##*/}
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \   ensure: present" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \   dest_folder: group-2" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \     sha1: `(cd /tmp/$today/group-2/; sha1sum ${i##*/} | awk '{ print $1 }')`" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \     url: filestore://testfolder/testfolder/${today}/group-2/${i##*/}" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a -  file:" "$file"
done

######GROUP-3
for i in ${group_3[@]}; do
   #echo $i
   #echo ${i##*/}
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \   ensure: present" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \   dest_folder: group-3" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \     sha1: `(cd /tmp/$today/group-3/; sha1sum ${i##*/} | awk '{ print $1 }')`" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \     url: filestore://testfolder/testfoldedf/${today}/group-3/${i##*/}" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a -  file:" "$file"
done

######GROUP-4
for i in ${group_4[@]}; do
   #echo $i
   #echo ${i##*/}
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \   ensure: present" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \   dest_folder: group-4" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \     sha1: `(cd /tmp/$today/group-4/; sha1sum ${i##*/} | awk '{ print $1 }')`" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \     url: filestore://testfolder/testfolder/${today}/group-4/${i##*/}" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a -  file:" "$file"
done

######GROUP-5
for i in ${group_5[@]}; do
   #echo $i
   #echo ${i##*/}
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \   ensure: present" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \   dest_folder: group-5" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \     sha1: `(cd /tmp/$today/group-5/; sha1sum ${i##*/} | awk '{ print $1 }')`" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a  \     url: filestore://testfolder/testfolder/${today}/group-5/${i##*/}" "$file"
   sed -i "/trm_data_file/a -  file:" "$file"
done
```

testfile.py:

```
"some Python code(not relevant)"
trm_data_files:
"Place where lines get inserted"
"some Python code(not relevant)"
```

Comment: please show extracts of .sh and .py file to help understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that you are using the full path to the `testfile.py` script in your shell script. When Ansible runs shell commands, it does this from a different location, e.g. the `/tmp` directory. Using the full, absolute path to your Python script will ensure that it can be found in this case.

You can run Ansible with the `-vvv` parameter to see the location of the script when it gets executed by Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

the createlines.sh seems to be present on targeted host but not the py file.

you should ensure that the py file is either copied and present on the target host.

Comment: its there /var/opt/alu/deploy/hieradata/testfile.py. I have it right on my screen. The file is 100% there

Comment: Can you try to use the full path of the `testfile.py` file in your script? Just to make sure that it can be found...

Comment: @nwinkler the script works and does everything as it should. It adds the lines correctly and also finds the file. It only gets into trouble when i play the ansible-playbook.The script is also in the same dir as the testfile.py

Comment: Ansible sometime runs scripts from a different directory - you should see that if you run Ansible with the `-vvv` flag. Trying the absolute path was not meant as a permanent fix, just for verifying whether it can find the script. I'd give it a try...